# OLAP dimension for Age

Tags: ssas, olap

We have a client table with a field DateOfBirth.

I'm new to MS Analysis Services, OLAP and data cubes. I'm trying to report on client metrics by age categories (18-25,26-35,35-50,50-65,66+)

I don't see a way to accomplish this. (Note: I'm not concerned with age at the time of a sale. I'm interested in knowing the age distribution of my current active customers).

Answer (score 2):

You can create either a TSQL or Named Calculation in the Data Source View that calculates the CurrentAge based on the DOB field. 
You will likely also want to implement another similarly derived field that assigns the CurrentAge Value a Bucket in your date range. this is a simple TSQL Case statement.

Depending on how large the client table is (and the analytical purpose), you may want to make this into a fact table or at least use snowflaking to separate this from the other relatively static attribute fields in the client table.